# 14 CFR § 91.213 - Inoperative instruments and equipment. <Cessna 172S NAV III>

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations, equipment, airworthiness

I am working on a commercial right now, but still, this confuses me a lot.

For example, during the preflight, I found that the airplane has inoperative equipment. And our operator has no MEL. Then I need to follow 91.213(d) since we do not have a MEL.

1. Check VFR-day type certificate
2. Check KOEL
3. Check AD's
4. Check 91.205

KOEL, 91.205 are pretty easy to understand.

But 1. VFR-day type certificate. I looked at TCDS a lot, but I cannot find any equipment list.

On the Comprehensive Equipment List (Section 6) R = Required items or equipment for FAA certification. Does it mean that the equipment listed on the CEL, and indicated with R, are considered as TCDS VFR-day type certificate?

Looking at [this page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46233/is-the-standby-altimeter-required-for-day-vfr-flight-in-a-c172-nav-iii)

> In summary:
> The standby altimeter is marked as required in the Comprehensive Equipment List because it's an IFR certification requirement
> Operationally, the standby altimeter is only required for IFR flight, per the KOEL

Basically, Pondlife wrote that

> The Comprehensive Equipment List (section 6 in the POH) lists all the equipment required by the type certificate:

If the equipment is required by any operations (VFR-day, VFR-night, IFR-day, IFR-night), it should be required by CEL. However, the alternate static air source is required by KOEL (IFR operations) not required by CEL (S).

[image: KOEL]
[image: CEL]

3. AD's. I know how to look them up on the FAA website. However, what if the check airman asked me to verify if it is not required by AD, how should I verify that the inoperative equipment is not required by AD?

Sorry for the language. I am an international student, not fluent in English. But I really appreciate your help.